# Fiber product of two affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $V_1$, $V_2$ are two irreducible affine varieties. Suppose we have finite maps $f_i: V_i\to \mathbb{A}^1(k)$. How can we prove that the fiber product $V_1\times_{\mathbb{A}^1(k)} V_2$ is again irreducible? If not then what conditions will enable the fiber product irreducible.

Here finite map means the map on the coordinate rings are finite.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you define the coordinate ring of $V_1\times_{\mathbb{A}^1(k)} V_2$ in term of $f_i$ and that of $V_i$

Comment: @reuns I think it is the tensor product of coordiante rings of $V_i$'s and the tensor product is taken over the base ring $k[x]$? Here the coordinate ring of $V_i$ is considered as $k[x]$-module via the maps $f_i^*$?

Comment: Yes I think it makes sense : $f_i \in k[V_i], k[V_i] = k[f_i][X_i]/J_i$ then $k[V_1 \times_f V_2]= k[f_1,f_2]/(f_1-f_2)[X_1,X_2]/(J_1,J_2)$. It is an integral domain iff $k[V_1 \times_f V_2] \cap \overline{k(f_1)}$ is an integral domain which doesn't have to happen for example if $k[V_1],k[V_2]$ both contain $\sqrt{f_1},\sqrt{f_2}$.

Comment: @reuns Can you please give me some explicit examples where this is not irreducible?

Comment: $k[V_1]=k[x,y]/(y^2-x),k[V_2]=k[x,z]/(z^2-x)$, $f(x,.)= x$, $k[V_1\times_f V_2]=k[x,y]/(y^2-x)\otimes_{k[x]} k[x,z]/(z^2-x)=k[x,y,z]/(y^2-x,z^2-x)$ $=k[x,y,z]/(y^2-x,(z+y)(z-y))\cong k[x,y,z]/(y^2-x,z+y)\times k[x,y,z]/(y^2-x,z-y)$. And I meant $V_1\times_f V_2$ is irreducible iff $k(V_1)  \cap \overline{k(f_1)},k(V_2)  \cap \overline{k(f_2)}$ are linearly independent fields that is their compositum is their tensor product (if $k[V_i]  \cap \overline{k(f_i)}$ is integrally closed the above works)